# SQL, Adding columns in different tables then doing an expression, group by date and name

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in which I my goal is to create a new column that calculates Calls per hour by simply dividing Calls by Hours. However, first I want to add the hours from table2 to table 1 before doing that calculation, adding the hours for the corresponding Name and Date.

```
Table1:

Name    Calls     Hours     Date
--------------------------------------
John    50        3         9/10/2012
Paul    25        2         9/10/2012
Cindy   60        3         9/10/2012
David   50        2.5       9/10/2012
John    45        4         9/9/2012
Paul    50        5         9/9/2012
Cindy   20        2         9/9/2012
David   20        2         9/9/2012

Table 2:

Date         Name     Hours     
------------------------------
9/10/2012    John       1
9/10/2012    Paul       2
9/10/2012    Cindy      2
9/9/2012     John       2.5
9/9/2012     Paul       1.5
9/9/2012     Cindy      0.5
```

Ultimately my desired query output is this:

```
Name    Calls   TotalHours    CallsPerHour   Date
-----------------------------------------------------
John    50      4             12.5           9/10/2012
Paul    25      4             6.25           9/10/2012
Cindy   60      5             12             9/10/2012
David   50      2.5           20             9/10/2012
John    45      6.5           6.9230         9/9/2012
Paul    50      6.5           7.6923         9/9/2012
Cindy   20      2.5           8              9/9/2012
David   20      2             10             9/9/2012
```

P.S. Names are unique in db.

Comment: There will only be on instance per person per date in both tables. There is one more thing I failed to mention: t2 will some times have no instance of an individual. I tried to below answers they work however if a individual doesn't show in table2 for a particular date than the person won't show if they show in table1. I have changed the tables to reflect this.

Comment: @David - I agree the LEFT OUTER JOIN methods are definitely cleaner, but I would just like to point out that the way my query was written, a person will still show up in the results even if they aren't in table 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both tables can have only one row per `Name` per `Date`, you don't need a `GROUP BY` query.  Use `LEFT JOIN` to accommodate missing Name/Date combinations in `TableTwo`.

```
SELECT
    t1.Name, 
    t1.Calls,
    t1.Hours + Nz(t2.Hours,0) AS TotalHours,
    t1.Calls / (t1.Hours + Nz(t2.Hours,0)) AS CallsPerHour,
    t1.Date
FROM
    TableOne AS t1
    LEFT JOIN TableTwo AS t2
    ON
        t1.Name = t2.Name
    AND t1.Date = t2.Date;
```

Using your revised sample data, this is the result set from that query.

```
Name   Calls TotalHours     CallsPerHour Date
John      50          4             12.5 9/10/2012
Paul      25          4             6.25 9/10/2012
Cindy     60          5               12 9/10/2012
David     50        2.5               20 9/10/2012
John      45        6.5 6.92307692307692  9/9/2012
Paul      50        6.5 7.69230769230769  9/9/2012
Cindy     20        2.5                8  9/9/2012
David     20          2               10  9/9/2012
```

Answer (score 3):

is this what you are after?

```
select  t1.name, 
        t1.calls,
        t1.hours + t2.hours as TotalHours,
        t1.calls / (t1.hours + t2.hours) as CallsPerHour,
        t1.date
from    table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.date = t2.date
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `JOIN` the tables and then apply the `GROUP BY`

```
select t1.name,
    t1.calls,
    sum(t1.hours + nz(t2.hours, 0)) as TotalHours,
    t1.calls / sum(t1.hours + nz(t2.hours, 0)) as CallsPerHour,
    t1.date
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.name = t2.name
    and t1.date = t2.date
group by t1.name, t1.calls, t1.date
```

Comment: @HansUp you are correct, I edited my answer to include the `NZ()` on the t2.hours. thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Calls) AS TotalCalls, SUM(Hours) AS TotalHours, 
    SUM(Calls) / SUM(Hours)  AS CallsPerHour, Date
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Calls, Hours, Date FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, 0, Hours, Date  FROM Table2
) BothTables
GROUP BY Name, Date
ORDER BY Date DESC, SUM(Calls) / SUM(Hours) DESC
```